# Python: Matrix multiplication via array slicing

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For an exercise of my programming class (we are using Python), I have to write a program that implements Matrix multiplication. The point is, that we should do this via array slicing and vector operations while trying to avoid using loops.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this without any loop. Using array slicing I could figure out a way to solve this with a loop nested within another loop instead of the direct way where you need three nested loops.

But how to do this without any loop?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what code you are allowed to use, and what not.  `matrix product` is a built into `numpy` either as `np.dot` or `@` (or `np.einsum`).  All can handle 1d arrays ("vector") or 2d (or higher).  In `numpy` a 1d array is no more special than a 2d one.

Comment: Hm, I suppose using .dot and .einsum is not allowed in this case, because it is explicitly mentioned to use array slicing. I suppose it is expected to use some kind of trick with clever indexing as a solution for this exercise.

Comment: I don't don't know what they mean by `array slicing`, especially if you can't use a `loop`.  But then I don't know what topics have been covered in the class up to this point.  A well designed class will give you exercises that use the concept that you just covered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code

```
import numpy as np 

# input two matrices 
mat1 = ([1, 6, 5],[3 ,4, 8],[2, 12, 3]) 
mat2 = ([3, 4, 6],[5, 6, 7],[6,56, 7]) 

# This will return dot product 
res = np.dot(mat1,mat2) 
//Output
[[ 63 320  83]
 [ 77 484 102]
 [ 84 248 117]]
```

Please read the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html?highlight=dot#numpy.dot) for future reference rather than asking for help straightaway since the documentation for numpy and python libraries is expansive and well written.

Comment: As hpaulj mentioned, I was not specific enough. I suppose using .dot and .einsum is not allowed in this case, because it is explicitly mentioned to use array slicing. I suppose it is expected to use some kind of trick with clever indexing as a solution for this exercise.